# WPF pop up is behaving differently in English language PC and Japanese language PC

Tags: wpf, popup

I have WPF window application, i am trying to pop up window and with that window doing some configuration. So the pop up window is showing properly in english language PC. but when i open the pop up in japanese language pc it is not showing properly. so i want to know the reason behind this. is WPF pop up has different default width limitation with different language PCs? OR something else?

[Below is EN PC result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm3Sq.png)

[Below is JA PC result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAiwv.png)

basically I want to know the route cause.

Thank You..

I Set pop up max with to some number it worked fine in both language PCs.

Comment: Is it possible it's just different font size settings on the OS and the language difference is just coincidental?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the panel used here is not `Grid` but some other custom UI components. Irrespective of culture info, you can fix the buttons like the following xaml and resize to any width.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This panel will serve as a outline layout and for internal combobox and label controls you could use a `StackPanel` and set its `Orientation` property to *Horizontal*